# Como ocultar um objeto em javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando ocultar um objeto em JavaScript, estou usando o comando  **`style.display = 'none';`** mas sem sucesso ainda.

**Como posso ocultar o objeto por JavaScript, não por CSS?**

objeto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o codigo fonte esta nesta pagina
http://natupote.net16.net/

https://embed.plnkr.co/fXDmAe6uClOY80AIGwp9/

Comment: Porque o form-tab-2 não está em: /*BOTAO IR PARA BANDEIJA*/ ?

Comment: porque ele eu nao quero ocultar ele por CSS, somente por javascript, quero ocultar e exibir ele com o pressionar de um botao que farei futuramente, mas o foco do problema e ocultar o botao por javascript mesmo

Comment: eu fiz o q vc disse pelo console do chrome e funcionou mesmo, mas eu estou tentando anexar o comando que vc disse no codigo fonte da pagina, para que execute sozinho, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: eu estou editando pelop plnkr https://embed.plnkr.co/fXDmAe6uClOY80AIGwp9/ se vc abrir vai ver q eu colei seu comando no <script> e não tive sucesso ainda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma forma maneira de ocultar este elemento Html:

```
document.getElementById("form-tab-2").style.display = "none";
```

**Para testar:** acesse a URL da página com o Google Chrome, em seguida pressione F12, clique na opção "Console", digite o comando acima no console e tecle ENTER.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após digitar e teclar enter:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para aplicar ao seu JavaScript e ter certeza que este elemento não está sendo exibido, coloque o código abaixo no início de seu JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {   
    setTimeout(function(){
         document.getElementById("form-tab-2").style.display = "none"; 
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Eu colei este comando e não ocultou ainda

Comment: eu estou fazendo ele no plunkr https://embed.plnkr.co/fXDmAe6uClOY80AIGwp9/

Comment: entendi, funciona mesmo, mas estou tentando anexar este comando no codigo fonte da pagina, para que na inicialização oculte o objeto, ainda sem sucesso...

Comment: No plunk funcionou: coloque o código abaixo no início de seu JavaScript:

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {   
        setTimeout(function(){
             document.getElementById("form-tab-2").style.display = "none"; 
        }, 1000);
    });

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Testou? Deu certo?

Comment: funcionou sim, obrigado, vc fez em 50 min oq eu to tentando fazer  ja faz 1 dia